# Put item on DynamoDB table using AWS SDK for Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm new to javascript and node.js and was wondering if someone can help me figure out the syntax of putting a new item onto an existing table on AWS Dynamodb through their node.js SDK. Here's what I have so far. Is there an example for what I'm trying to do? If anyone could point me in the right direction, it'd be much appreciated.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.loadFromPath('./config.json');
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

var item = {
    // I need to put the an item with a the primary key of "id", and an attribute called "item"
    // I'm new to js and node.js, so if somebody could help me understand the documentation
    // http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/frames.html#!http%3A//docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB_20120810.html
}

dynamodb.putItem({TableName: 'log_dev', Item: item}, function(err, data){
    if (err) {
    console.log(err); // an error occurred
    } else {
    console.log(data); // successful response
    }
});
```

Answer (score 36):

```
dynamoDB.putItem(
{
    "TableName": "Table1",
    "Item": {
        "Color": {"S": "white"},
        "Name": {"S": "fancy vase"},
        "Weight": {"N": "2"},
        "LastName":{"S": "Kumar"}
    }
}, function(result) {
    result.on('data', function(chunk) {
        console.log("" + chunk);
    });
});
console.log("Items are succesfully ingested in table ..................");
```

Comment: [dynamoDb-marshaler](https://github.com/CascadeEnergy/dynamoDb-marshaler) will help ease the pain of formatting

Answer (score 5):

I expect your "id" to be numeric...

```
var item = {
    "id": {"N": 1234},
    "title": {"S": "Foobar"}
}
```

Note that with DynamoDB you specify the data type (*N* » numeric, *S* » string, *B* » binary) at table creation, only for the primary key (*HashKey* or *HashKey+RangeKey*). All other columns are allowed to vary in their data type, and can be seen as key-value pairs. So it is essential for DynamoDB to always encode the data type with the item attributes.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think muhqu's answer works, I believe the value of the attribute has to be a string.

```
var item = {
"id": {"N": "1234"},
"title": {"S": "Foobar"} }
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#putItem-property

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using `documentClient` as it makes it easier to read and write data in dynamoDb. Also using conditional putItem will make sure the item is unique and doesn't overwrite existing item. "attribute_not_exists" checks if the userId in the example doesn't exist. If userId exists, it throws an error.  Hope it's not too late :P

```html
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.loadFromPath('./config.json');
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

var item = {
"userId" : {"N":"12345678"},
"name":{"S":"Bob"}
}

var dbParam= {
TableName: tableName,
Item:item,
ConditionExpression: 'attribute_not_exists(#u) or #u = :userId',
ExpressionAttributeNames: { "#u" : "userId"}
}

dynamodb.putItem(dbParam, function(err,data) {
if(err){
console.log("err",err);
}
else{
console.log("data",data)
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `aws-sdk` you would use something like the following:

```
import { DynamoDB } from 'aws-sdk';

const dynamo = new DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

const main = async () => {
    const results = await dynamo
        .put({
            TableName: 'people',
            Item: {
              dateCreated: { S: new Date().toUTCString() },
              name: { S: name },
            },
        })
        .promise();

    console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
};

main();
```